# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'InputSelected', function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, angular-cli, build-error

I have a legacy code built on angular 2. Here is the code i have on a file named users.input.ts. It compiles successfully. But when i try to ng build I get compilation errors. Can anyone help me with what i have to do?

**input-select.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';
import { InputSelectSearchComponent } from '../input-select-search/input-select-search.component';
import { InputBase } from '../../classes/input-base';
import { UIStylekitService } from '../../ui-stylekit.service';

export class InputSelect extends InputBase<string> {
  controlType = 'select';
  options: {value: string, label: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'input-select',
  templateUrl: 'input-select.component.html',
  inputs: ['form','input']
})
export class InputSelectComponent extends InputSelectSearchComponent {

  constructor(
    private __Stylekit: UIStylekitService ) { 
      super(__Stylekit);
  }

}
```

**users.input.ts**

```
import { InputBase, InputSelect } from '../../../ui-stylekit';

export const UsersInputs: InputBase<any>[] = [
  new InputSelect({
    key: 'title',
    label: 'Title',
    options: [
      { value: 'Mr', label: 'Mr'},
      { value: 'Mrs', label: 'Mrs'},
      { value: 'Miss', label: 'Miss'},
      { value: 'Ms', label: 'Ms'},
      { value: 'Prof', label: 'Prof'},
      { value: 'Dr', label: 'Dr'}
    ],
    required: false,
    groupClass: 'half',
  })
];
```

**admin.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminGuard } from '../shared/';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';

import { ListComponent, UpdateComponent, CreateComponent } from '../ui/components/';

import { UsersInputs } from '../shared/config/';
import { UsersConfig } from '../shared/config/';

export const AdminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'users', component: ListComponent, data: { config: UsersConfig }, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
      { path: 'users/edit/:id', component: UpdateComponent, data: { config: UsersConfig, inputs: UsersInputs }, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
      { path: 'users/create', component: CreateComponent, data: { config: UsersConfig, inputs: UsersInputs }, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
    ]
  }
];
```

**Error**

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Calling function 'InputSelect', function calls are not supported.
>   Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an
>   exported function

Comment: please show InputSelect's code, or at least how you declare/export the class

Comment: @David: I've updated the question to include the code for InputSelect class

Comment: And where/how do you use UsersInputs?

Comment: @David: I've used it in a files named admin.routes.ts. I've updated the question to include that file too.

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried your code with angular (5 though) and it worked when building with aot. Are you sure the error is for the declaration of the `UsersInputs` variable? Instead of directly using new in the array, maybe try creating a factory function that instantiate the objects?

Comment: @BalajiViswanath are you using angular 4? which version of cli?

Comment: I hope you are using ng version compatible with angular 2? And its not getting mixed up with a newer version. Also if it is a open project then share the repo url.